# Issues with animating view for new screen sizes

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, animatewithduration

In my app, I have two views within my main view controller. One is for entering the details about your budget. The other is for viewing the current state of your budget.

When the enter button is tapped on the entry view, that view slides down to reveal the current budget view.

In viewWillAppear I have some code that is executed if the enter button has been tapped but the view has not been moved (this happens when the app has been closed down completely and reopened).

The reset button does the opposite of the enter button and slides the view back up.

The issue is that sometimes when the reset button is tapped, the view starts to slide up but then stops near the bottom of the view. This all worked great before I updated my app to work on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus, so I assume there is something wrong with my coordinate calculations. I just haven't been able to figure it out. Here is how it looks when it gets stuck:

[image]

Reset button:

```
    self.budgetEntryView.hidden = false
    resetButtonNav.enabled = false

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.budgetEntryView.center = CGPointMake(self.budgetEntryView.center.x, self.budgetEntryView.center.y - 500)
        }, completion: { (finished:Bool) in
            self.budgetDisplayView.hidden = true
```

viewWillAppear:

```
        if enterButtonTapped == true && self.budgetEntryView.center.y != 784 {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.budgetEntryView.center = CGPointMake(self.budgetEntryView.center.x, self.budgetEntryView.center.y + 500)
            }, completion: { (finished:Bool) in self.budgetEntryView.hidden = true })
        }
```

Enter Button:

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.budgetEntryView.center = CGPointMake(self.budgetEntryView.center.x, self.budgetEntryView.center.y + 500)
        }, completion: { (finished:Bool) in self.budgetEntryView.hidden = true })
```

Comment: Do you use autolayout? If so, you might think about animating the constraints instead of width/height/position of the views.

Comment: Nope. I tried using auto layout early on but I really didn't like it. I use it for the Today Widget since it's a much more simple UI but I want to avoid using it for the main app. Is there nothing obviously wrong with the code that could cause an issue that you can see?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see something obvious. Place several println() statements in your code to check if something happens to the center coordinate. And better use `CGPoint(...)` instead of `CGPointMake(...)`

Comment: Ah through using println, I've found that at some point it jumps for 868 as it should be, to 1368. Thanks for your help. I'll keep testing things to see if I can find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was fairly simple once I used println as suggested to find the issue.

Basically, I just had to add the coordinates that the view will be positioned at on the new screen sizes like this:

```
    if enterButtonTapped == true && self.budgetEntryView.center.y != 784 && self.budgetEntryView.center.y != 868 && self.budgetEntryView.center.y != 740 && self.budgetEntryView.center.y != 833.5 {
```